# Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010 branch visualizations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, version-control, tfs, branch

While maintaining code branches for a particular project I am noticing that the source control panel does not align with the branching hierarchy for the project, confirmed by visualizing the hierarchy by clicking on the branch `<Context Click> | Branching and Merging | View Hierarchy`.

The source explorer picture at  [MSDN - Working with TFS 2010 Code Branches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_branchingandmerging_topic2.aspx) shows plus signs in the source explorer **as expected.**

I also tried creating a new branch, changing the "Target Branch Name" to `$/Net Pr/Ye/Pe/New-Branch` and received error:

> TF203028: You cannot create a branch at .. .. because a branch already exists.

[image: My TFS implementation - "Pe" is a child node of "Ye", yet displays in source control directly under the project node.]

---Add---

How do I get my source explorer to reflect the branching hierarchy, as indicated in the MSDN reference?

---Add---

[image: branch hierarchy.]

Comment: What's the question?  What are you seeing and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: Expecting plus signs on the source control explorer showing the branches, reflective of the hierarchy.  I updated the question for clarity @EdwardThomson .

Comment: I'm still not sure I'm following.  The disclosure triangles are painted for any folder item in the tree, regardless of whether it's a branch object or not... It looks like in your screenshot you have a disclosure triangle for "Ye (clipped)", and it's expanded.  The only difference between a triangle and a plus sign is your Windows theme, the screenshot you reference was taken with an older theme...

Comment: They're clipped so I don't have to rename the folders, but that is source code within the branch.  Because "Pe" branches from "Ye" I expected to see "Pe" as a subdirectory-object of "Ye." I am adding a new picture of the hierarchy now.

Comment: Hmm.  I think I see what you're asking.  You can't have a branch object as a child of another branch object - you'd need to have them side-by-side.  My project, for example, has `$/Project/main`, and then feature branches in `$/Project/features/branchname` and release branches in `$/Project/branches/1.0`.  Unfortunately, there's only SCE browsing (ie, the namespace browsing) and the branch viz that you found with the `View Hierarchy` button.  There's not really a join of those two concepts in the UI.  But it's an interesting question, so I hope somebody else has a solution.